# Distance calculation in MySQL different from Great Circle Mapper

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out how to match the result of the [Great Circle Mapper](http://www.gcmap.com/).

```
SELECT 3959 * 
ACOS(
     COS(RADIANS(41.97444444)) * 
     COS(RADIANS(28.42944444)) * 
     COS(RADIANS(-87.90666667) - RADIANS(-81.30888889)) + 
     SIN (RADIANS(41.97444444)) * 
     SIN(RADIANS(28.42944444))
    ) AS `distance`
```

Returns `1006.5099532670922`

However, GCMap produces [`1005 miles`](http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=ORD-MCO)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibliy a difference in floating-point precision? Do you know their exact input numbers / algos used (or rather if the ones in-question are precise)?

Comment: @Rogue http://www.gcmap.com/faq/gccalc

Comment: Implementing Vincenty also produces the same result.